# If and Elif/Else choices not doing what i expect them to do

Tags: python, codio

I tell python

```
Game=input
```

and then

```
if Game=="1":
    print("Guess The Number Selected")
```

and then again

```
if Game=="2":
    print("Hangman Selected")
```

But then it ends up printing both!
Also I do

```
NumberChoice=input

NumberGuess=input
```

Then I give it

```
if NumberGuess=="NumberChoice":
    print("Congratulations! You Win.")
else:
    print("Incorrect! Try Again.")
```

Instead of doing both it ends up doing

```
Incorrect! Try Again.
```

It does that twice even when I input the correct number

Comment: try type(Game) after Game=input

Comment: You're not telling us everything. The behavior you describe in the first part of your post is impossible, you have some other code that you don't show us. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes arround 1 and 2 in your two first if statement

As well, change

```
`if NumberGuess=="NumberChoice":`
```

to

```
`if NumberGuess == NumberChoice:`
```

So you can compare values

Final code should look lik

```
Game=input("select a game")
if Game==1:
    print("Guess The Number Selected")

elif Game==2:
    print("Hangman Selected")

NumberChoice=input("choose a number")
NumberGuess=input("guess a number")
if NumberGuess==NumberChoice:
    print("Congratulations! You Win.")
else:
    print("Incorrect! Try Again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be: `Game=input()`.
`Game=input` just refers to the function instead of calling it.